# Is LASTor client available to the end user?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am reading through a paper entitled: LASTor: A Low-Latency AS-Aware Tor Client here: "http://freehaven.net/anonbib/cache/oakland2012-lastor.pdf".

The authors said that they would publish LASTor client for public use, but I could not find it anywhere on the Internet. Does anyone know where I can get LASTor Client, or is it already a death project?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the idea in general is being evaluated under [#6328](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6328), I don't think their code ever emerged and it seems from the [review of LASTor](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6328#comment:7) on the ticket that it wasn't suitable.

You may also be interested in reading [Research problem: measuring the safety of the Tor network](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/research-problem-measuring-safety-tor-network).

Comment: thank you so much for your prompt response to my question with reference links.